# Cómo cambiar valor de un atributo usando una condición? Java

Tags: java, condiciones, parametros, atributos, bluej

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:
Tengo que configurar el valor de una variable usando una condición.

```
public class CarToBuy{
private int Price;
private boolean sold; //initialized as sold=false;

public CarToBuy(int Price){
   this.Price=Price;
   sold=false;
}
public void ChangePrice(int Price){
        if (sold==false){
        this.Price= Price;
    } else if (sold==true) {
          System.out.println("The Car has been Sold. Is not possible to change the price");
    }
   }
}
```

La cuestión es que aunque **sold** sea igual a **true**, cuando llame a ChangePrice() de igual manera me pedirá el parametro Price, luego hará la condición y si es true saldrá el mensaje cosa que veo innecesaria.

Pero quisiera saber si es posible hacer primero la condición para que  si en caso de que sold=true, no tenga que poner el parametro Price.

Gracias

Comment: "...cosa que veo innecesaria." Por qué consideras que es innecesario? En algún momento debes chequear el parámetro `sold` para saber si puedes modificar el precio del auto o no. Es decir, es una forma de impedir que el precio del auto se modifique si la variable `sold` es `true`. Recuerda que la finalidad del método `ChangePrice(int Price)` es justamente cambiar el precio del auto. Por lo tanto, preguntate si tendría sentido llamar al método sin un precio a cambiar. El hecho de que se imprima un mensaje de error es justamente para controlar esta condición de que no se haya vendido el auto.

Comment: Entonces lo que buscas es eliminar el mensaje cuando *sold == true* ? Y evaluar una sola de las condiciones ?

Comment: Lo que queria es evaluar antes de introducir el parámetro. Si llamas al método, te pedirá sí o sí que introduzcas un valor, independientemente de si es false o true.
Pero ahora entiendo mejor el uso de este método. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problema

Por lo que entiendo, lo que quieres es no tener que enviar el parametro `int Price` a tu método `public void ChangePrice(int Price)` en caso de que el atributo `private boolean sold` sea igual a `true`.

Ahora bien, recuerda que la finalidad del método `public void ChangePrice(int Price)` es justamente cambiar el precio del auto. Sin embargo, según tu código hay una condición que debe cumplirse para que esto se lleve a cabo, y es que la variable `sold` debe ser `false` para que se pueda cambiar el precio del auto.

Estableciendo lo anterior, ¿para qué llamarías al método `ChangePrice` sin el parámetro price? si lo que quieres lograr con dicho método es cambiar el precio del auto. Creo que aquí hay una confusión semántica con respecto al método.

> Pero quisiera saber si es posible hacer primero la condición para que si en caso de que sold=true, no tenga que poner el parametro Price.

### Solución

Para "hacer primero la condición" lo que podrías hacer es crear un nuevo método en la Clase `CarToBuy` que te de a conocer si el precio del auto puede ser modificado o no. Esto sería:

```java
public class CarToBuy{
private int Price;
private boolean sold; //initialized as sold=false;

public CarToBuy(int Price){
   this.Price = Price;
   sold = false;
}
public void ChangePrice(int newPrice){
    if (sold==false){ // Esta condición es necesaria para evitar cambiar el precio del auto si este fue vendido
       Price = newPrice;
    } else if (sold==true) {
       System.out.println("The Car has been Sold. Is not possible to change the price");
    }
   }
}

public boolean canChangePrice() { // <-- Puedes llamar a este método para saber si el precio del auto puede ser modificado o no, antes de cambiarlo.
   return !sold;
}
```

Comment: Sí, en efecto, habia un problema con la semántica. Ya lo he corregido y gracias por la colaboración.